# Best key to store UserState in external DB

Tags: database, botframework, storage

Currently, in my Bot app I was storing the UserProfile in my UserState, and accessing it through accessors.

Now I just started storing the UserProfile in a database. The key I'm using to retrieve the profile of a certain user is his User Id, which I retrieve from:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity.From.Id
```

Is it reliable? Does this user realted key expire? If that's the case what key should I use, or how should I link a bot user with the profile on my database?

Comment: Is this a transative web bot (like a "Help" bot on a website") or perhaps something embedded in, for example, Teams or Slack or so?

Comment: It's embedded in, users have to authenticate once at the very start of the conversation and then can start using the service indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above, when the bot is embedded in another tool (e.g. Teams, Slack, etc.), the `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity.From.Id` is perfect and will remain the same for the same user across all visits.

Comment: Just fyi, I haven't -tested- this in slack, but I build bots for Teams and it works perfectly. In Teams, you actually also get send an "aadObjectId", which maps to the users Azure AD object id